# Optimize the C# setup program to install application immediately

Tags: c#

I have created on Setup for my application in Visual studio 2015. I when i try to install it takes 1-2 minutes to start the installation. It stop for few minutes then it ask for Administrative username and password. Once i provide the username and password then it start the installation.

My question is how i avoid these time to make installation faster.

Comment: How are you creating your setup file? Is it using the WiX Toolset, or some other plugin? If I recall correctly, VS stopped having native support for producing installers in 2013 (except for Click-Once, but based on your description, this doesn't sound like Click-Once).

Comment: I have created in Visual Studio 2015 through setup and deployment template.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, it *sounds* like you're using the InstallShield templates. The [WiX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) is what I would recommend for building inside of Visual Studio. It's considered stable at this point (in the v3 chain), and the docs are pretty solid. For many use-cases, I believe it probably has everything you need. There are, of course, other products out there (such as [InstallShield](https://www.flexerasoftware.com/producer/products/software-installation/installshield-software-installer/)). One of the advertised benefits of using the WiX Toolset is that it keeps your installer organized in human-readable (and therefore versionable) source. It also has solid integration with Visual Studio and MSBuild.

I hope it is safe to assume that this is for a relatively young product/installer. If such is the case, you will want to get some information on [Windows Installer upgrades](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370579(v=vs.85).aspx) and create a release strategy for your installer.

About the installation slowness, I think it's hard to say without more information. You can emit some very detailed logs using the `msiexec` command line switches. For a product installer called `installer.msi`, you can run `msiexec /I installer.msi /l* .\mySetuplog.log`, which will give you some (extremely verbose) information about the entire installation process (with timestamps), so you can see what steps are taking the longest. You can also adjust the level of verbosity based on your needs. `msiexec /?` can help you determine the level of verbosity you need.

Just from the experience I've had with using installer (development) products, I've found that InstallShield is great for teams that are packaging applications, but the usage scenario is more geared towards people building installers on the delivery side of software development (not the development side). If you're trying to build from Visual Studio, I would personally recommend WiX. It's easy to work with, has lots of documentation, and several answers in the community for some common issues.